# arangodb AQL aggregate result and return object

Tags: arangodb, aql

I want to aggregate some ratings in AQL.
The below query

```
FOR l IN locations
COLLECT rating = l.rating WITH COUNT INTO ratings
RETURN {[rating]: ratings}
```

returns and array of object:

```
[
  {
    "Good": 4639
  },
  {
    "Bad": 517
  },
  {
    "So so": 1017
  }
]
```

what I need is one object like:

```
[
  {
    "Good": 4639,
    "Bad": 517,
    "So so": 1017
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MERGE`([doc](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/functions-document.html#merge)) to achieve the desired result:

```
RETURN MERGE (
  FOR l IN locations
    COLLECT rating = l.rating WITH COUNT INTO ratings
    RETURN {[rating]: ratings}
)
```

Tested with my `test` collection (using `prop2` rather than `rating`):

```
[
  {
    "baz": 1,
    "other": 2
  }
]
```

---